# How to define a concatenation function in typescript

Tags: typescript, function, concatenation

In Typescript How can I define a interface Calculator that can support concatenation?
Like:

```
interface Calculator {
    ...
}
 
let calcu: Calculator;
calcu(2).multiply(5).add(1)
```

I tried:

```
interface Calculator {
  (num: number): Calculator;
  multiply(num: number): Calculator;
  add(num: number): Calculator;
}
```

But I got the error that calcu is not instantiated:

```
Variable 'calcu' is used before being assigned
```

So my question is how I can define interface Calculator and how to instantiate calcu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces just define the shape of something, you probably should declare a `class` which can be instantiated with `new`.

e.g.

```
class Calculator
{
    constructor(public num: number) { }
    multiply(num: number)
    {
        this.num *= num;

        return this;
    }
    add(num: number)
    {
        this.num += num;

        return this;
    }
}

const calcu = new Calculator(2);
calcu.multiply(5).add(1);

console.log(calcu.num);
```

If you want to work directly with the interface and plain objects, that is possible but a huge pain, e.g.:

```
const calcu: Calculator = (() =>
{
    let value;

    const fun = function (num: number)
    {
        value = num;

        return fun;
    };
    fun['multiply'] = (num: number) =>
    {
        value *= num;
        return fun;
    };
    fun['add'] = (num: number) =>
    {
        value += num;
        return fun;
    };

    return fun;
})();

calcu(2).multiply(5).add(1);
```

*(You probably also would want to define a function that returns the internal value, currently it is completely hidden.)*